# Set values in dataframe with multiple element-wise conditions

Tags: python, pandas, location, element

I have a dataframe. I want to set all values that are less than x, in rows that have a certain parameter value, to a new value.

I try this, but nothing happens to my dataframe.

```
   df_data = {'A': [4, 4, 5, 5],
               'B': [4, 4, 4, 5],
               'C': [4, 5, 5, 5],
               'Bool': [True, True, False, False]}
    test_df = pd.DataFrame(df_data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'Bool'])
    test_df[test_df.iloc[:, :-1] < 5][test_df['Bool'] == True] = 99
    print(test_df)
```

I expect some elements in the test_df to have value 99.

Comment: The code you have written is not working.

Comment: You are absolutely right, because I forget `loc`, sorry - `test_df.loc[(test_df.iloc[:, :-1] < 5) & test_df['Bool'], 'A'] = 99`

Comment: I get error message:
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (16,) (4,)

Comment: yop, I see it. what is expcted output from your sample data?

Comment: df_data = {'A': [99, 99, 5, 5],
               'B': [99, 99, 99, 5],
               'C': [4, 5, 5, 5],
               'Bool': [True, True, False, False]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want chain boolean `DataFrame` with `&` for bitwise AND is necessary convert it to numpy array (N, 1) and then set new values with [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
m = (test_df.iloc[:, :-1] < 5).values & test_df['Bool'].values[:, None]
print (m)
[[ True  True  True]
 [ True  True False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]]

test_df.iloc[:, :-1] = test_df.iloc[:, :-1].mask(m, 99)
print(test_df)
    A   B   C   Bool
0  99  99  99   True
1  99  99   5   True
2   5   4   5  False
3   5   5   5  False
```

Comment: I get error message when creating m:
ValueError: Unable to coerce to DataFrame, shape must be (4, 3): given (4L, 1L)

Comment: m = (test_df.iloc[:, :-1] < 5) & (pd.DataFrame(pd.np.tile((test_df['Bool'].values[:, None] == True), (1, 3)))).values
    test_df.iloc[:, :-1] = test_df.iloc[:, :-1].mask(m, 99)

Comment: @muzzex can you test `m = (test_df.iloc[:, :-1].values < 5) & test_df['Bool'].values[:, None]
print (m)`

Comment: That last comment also work. Need the ".values".
Thanks jezrael for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
m = (test_df.iloc[:, :-1] < 5) & (pd.DataFrame(pd.np.tile((test_df['Bool'].values[:, None] == True), (1, 3)))).values
test_df.iloc[:, :-1] = test_df.iloc[:, :-1].mask(m, 99)
```